# How can I make hover box on the right side of my div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to modify [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_overlay_slideright)
 code, so the box would slide to the left side of the box.
I was thinking that I should just change in class .overlay `right: 0;` to   `right: 100%;`, but its not doing anything. It should look like this [image]
Also What should I do when when the box slides to the right side and I hover my mouse to it my box stays until I move my mouse away, how can I fix it?

Here is the css code when I did tha animation to the right side:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100%;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  this code to move the overlay to left on hover

```
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0; 
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
 width: 100%;
 left: -100%;
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  float:right;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0; 
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  left: -100%;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<h2>Slide in Overlay from the Right</h2>
<p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its not what I mean, the box should go out of the image to the left side, with the animation that is already provided by the link that I gave.

Comment: I added code when I was doing same idea but to the right side in my post

Comment: @MarkGolubev Check if you are looking for this

Comment: yes, but the only thing is it should start animation from the left corner

Comment: @MarkGolubev Updated

Comment: And I had second question that can I make it so when I hover to text box it would disappear?

Comment: @MarkGolubev You mean hover on `.text` .I think you have to use javascript for that

Comment: yah so the box would appear only when you hover on image

Comment: @MarkGolubev  add hover to `.overlay` and hide the overlay Or for hover on `.text` use javascript

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MmNXmN

**HTML**

```
<h2>Slide in Overlay from the Right</h2>
<p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>

<div class="container">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="text">Hello World</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 100%;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  right: 100%;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Yes, its very close, the only thing is I want animation to start from left corner (Its starting from right corner)

Comment: Updated https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MmNXmN . I just removed the right: 0; from the .overlay.

Comment: Yes! that's it! And I had second question that can I make it so when I hover to text box it would disappear?

Comment: @MarkGolubev You mean hover on `.text` .I think you have to use  javascript for that

Comment: @XYZ yah so the box would appear only when you hover on image

Comment: You could add .overlay:hover { display: none; } see example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MmNXmN . The box doesn't ease out but it's a simple solution that doesn't require JS.